# getCredentials method error when trying to run "Word Count" program in eclipse by importing all JAR files

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, hadoop

**Error** : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCredentials()Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/Credentials;
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.(Job.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance(Job.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getInstance(Job.java:195)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:20)

**Hadoop version 2.2.0**

**WordCount.java**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
public class WordCount {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
          System.out.println("usage: [input] [output]");
          System.exit(-1);
        }


        Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "word count");
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class); 
        job.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);  

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setJobName("WordCount");

        job.submit();






 }
}
```

**WordMapper.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
public class WordMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
private Text word = new Text();
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
 @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value,
        Context contex) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Break line into words for processing
        StringTokenizer wordList = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (wordList.hasMoreTokens()) {
       word.set(wordList.nextToken());
       contex.write(word, one);
      }
     }
    }
```

**SumReducer.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;



public class SumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

 private IntWritable totalWordCount = new IntWritable();

 @Override
 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int wordCount = 0;
  Iterator<IntWritable> it=values.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
   wordCount += it.next().get();
  }
  totalWordCount.set(wordCount);
  context.write(key, totalWordCount);
 }
}
```

Please let me know what can be done ?Latest mapreduce API is used for the program. All the jars that came with hadoop 2.2.0 are also imported into eclipse.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I made some changes and got few more lines of error as shown below !                                                                
 at WordCount.run(WordCount.java:24)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
 at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:47)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Eclipse plugin for Hadoop? If not that is the problem. With out the plugin, Eclipse if just running the `WordCount` class and Hadoop can't find the necessary jars. Bundle all the jars including `WordCount` and run it in Cluster.

If you want to run it from Eclipse you need Eclipse plugin. If you don't have one, you can build the plugin by following this [instructions](https://github.com/itsamiths/hadoop-eclipse-plugins)

Comment: I imported all hadoop jars, it dint show any errors when I saved the program

Comment: I also would like to mention that : 1. I dint installl hadoop my windows, I just downloaded hadoop 2.2.0 and loaded the jars into my eclipse. 2. My main aim of this application is to make a custom jar out of it to run on Amazon EMR instead of their default application. So I thought to make a WordCount jar I literally need not install hadoop but just import jars and write the application! Now should I go ahead with crating eclipse plugin or can I just create a jar knowing that my application is not running on eclipse and put it on EMR and see?

Comment: I would suggest to test in EMR.

Comment: Its working on EMR !. But to run on windows should I actually install hadoop or just bulidng the plugin and importing JARS and then running the application is enough ?.